# Blender in Windows 10

Tags: windows

I'm having some trouble with fresh installs of Blender on Windows 10. I've tried 2.79b and 2.78c and both do the same thing: they show the main window, then do nothing more.

I updated my graphics drivers, which helped an iota: before the upgrade, blender would eventually show (Not Responding), and now it doesn't.

In short, I am experiencing the exact same issue as [Blender app window BLANK after Windows 10 update](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108786/blender-app-window-blank-after-windows-10-update?rq=1)

Here is the startup output from 2.78c/2.79b:

2.78c:

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
read file
  Version 272 sub 2 date unknown hash unknown

ordered
 OBCube
 OBLamp
 OBCamera
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
ED_screen_refresh: set screen
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\python
SRNA Subclassed: 'Context'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
time bl_operators 0.0596
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Bone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'EditBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PoseBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'UIList'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Mesh'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Object'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Texture'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Header'
time bl_ui 0.1471
SRNA Subclassed: 'KeyingSetInfo'
time keyingsets_builtins 0.0045
SRNA Subclassed: 'Node'
SRNA Subclassed: 'NodeInternal'
SRNA Subclassed: 'ShaderNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'CompositorNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'TextureNode'
time nodeitems_builtins 0.0160
SRNA Subclassed: 'WindowManager'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_3ds
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_fbx
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_anim_bvh
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_ply
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_obj
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_x3d
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_stl
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_uv_layout
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_curve_svg
SRNA Subclassed: 'RenderEngine'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'AddonPreferences'
I0706 09:11:30.109755 14656 blender_python.cpp:182] Debug flags initialized to:
CPU flags:
  AVX2   : True
  AVX    : True
  SSE4.1 : True
  SSE3   : True
  SSE2   : True
CUDA flags:
 Adaptive Compile: False
OpenCL flags:
  Device type : ALL
  Kernel type : DEFAULT
  Debug       : False
        addon_utils.enable cycles
Python Script Load Time 0.3103
I0706 09:11:30.170783 14656 device_cuda.cpp:1346] CUEW initialization succeeded
I0706 09:11:30.170783 14656 device_cuda.cpp:1348] Found precompiled kernels
I0706 09:11:30.394778 14656 device_opencl.cpp:58] CLEW initialization succeeded.
```

2.79b:

```
Switching to fully guarded memory allocator.
read file
  Version 272 sub 2 date unknown hash unknown

ordered
 OBCube
 OBLamp
 OBCamera
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead
ED_screen_refresh: set screen
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python
SRNA Subclassed: 'Context'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
time bl_operators 0.0781
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Bone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'EditBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PoseBone'
SRNA Subclassed: 'UIList'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Mesh'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Object'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Texture'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Header'
time bl_ui 0.1822
SRNA Subclassed: 'KeyingSetInfo'
time keyingsets_builtins 0.0055
SRNA Subclassed: 'Node'
SRNA Subclassed: 'NodeInternal'
SRNA Subclassed: 'ShaderNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'CompositorNode'
SRNA Subclassed: 'TextureNode'
time nodeitems_builtins 0.0155
SRNA Subclassed: 'WindowManager'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_3ds
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_fbx
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_anim_bvh
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_ply
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_obj
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_scene_x3d
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_stl
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_mesh_uv_layout
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
        addon_utils.enable io_curve_svg
SRNA Subclassed: 'RenderEngine'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Panel'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Menu'
SRNA Subclassed: 'Operator'
SRNA Subclassed: 'PropertyGroup'
SRNA Subclassed: 'AddonPreferences'
I0706 09:16:59.436280 15536 blender_python.cpp:186] Debug flags initialized to:
CPU flags:
  AVX2   : True
  AVX    : True
  SSE4.1 : True
  SSE3   : True
  SSE2   : True
  QBVH   : True
  Split  : False
CUDA flags:
 Adaptive Compile: False
OpenCL flags:
  Device type    : ALL
  Kernel type    : DEFAULT
  Debug          : False
  Single program : True
  Memory limit   : zu
        addon_utils.enable cycles
Python Script Load Time 0.3843
I0706 09:16:59.480810 15536 device_opencl.cpp:59] CLEW initialization succeeded.
```

Comment: I would suggest uninstall and delete the startup.blend (if it is still around) and reinstall. This will remove any customisation you may have made.

Comment: @rob, sorry, I should have mentioned that this is a fresh install of Blender with no customisation

Comment: If it was me, I would try the steps here to use an alternate OpenGL DLL even though you do not get the specific error message https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEB_mZk64Dg .It is a software version of OpenGL and will run slower than expected but then that shows it is your GFX drivers at fault. You could also try the beta builds of Blender 2.8. What GFX card/drivers are you using?

Comment: What graphics card are you using? Blender works fine on my W10 machine + GTX750ti based graphics card

Comment: I've got an NVidia Quadro K2100M

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the blender source and ran it with visual studio attached. This was surprisingly easy. Normally, whenever I have to poke around in an open source project and try to get it running in Windows I feel as if the universe is against me.

The code is hanging inside `static cl_int device_opencl_get_num_platforms_safe(cl_uint *num_platforms)` (blender-git\blender\intern\cycles\device\device_opencl.cpp)

Commenting out or otherwise jumping over `clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, num_platforms);` gets me running in blender.

As far as I can tell (and I really have no idea), it's a driver issue made worse by this query to openCL.

Reading about openCL [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html), it seems that it isn't mission critical (for me - absolute beginner wanting to try sculpting), and that I could get by without having a GPU renderer.

Unfortunately, the OpenCL query code is called in a few places, such as when opening user preferences.

My less than ideal solution is to comment out the OpenCL query code and run a custom blender binary.